# Is there an R package for scoring the IPAQ long form (international physical activity questionnaire?

Tags: r, package

I'm using the IPAQ long from for measuring habitual physical activity.

I'd like to use R to calculate the categorical scores. There is a package available for the short form of the questionnaire https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/score/score.pdf.

Is anyone aware of a long form version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/Mariana-plr/IPAQlong. IPAQlong calculates the continuous and categorical scores for the IPAQ long form.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31413658)

Comment: Hi @Mariana I'm having problems with IPAQlong when `truncate = T`.  I get Error in `dplyr::case_when()` which seems to refer to the creation of categorical score `medium`. Are you able to help?

Comment: Hello @MarkDavies, sorry for the delay. The error is fixed in the new version of the package https://github.com/Mariana-plr/IPAQlong. Thank you for pointing it out!